# Inlay planar mesh onto curved mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, boolean-modifier

I am unsure if this is something that is possible, but I have 2 meshes, a planar mesh and a curved mesh. I want to project the planar mesh onto the curved mesh, inlaying it so that it is raised or depressed by the same amount on all sides.

I have tried a bunch of different boolean operations to get this to work but nothing has looked right, the sides are always cut way deeper than the top. Any suggestions?

I have attached an image of what I am looking at right now.[image]

Comment: It seems like the shrinkwrap modifier is what I am looking for, seeing if I can get that to work now

Comment: do you have an image of the final object it should create?

Comment: I don't. Easiest way to describe it would be if the planar mesh was a blanket and gravity pulled it down over the bottom mesh

Comment: what happens to the sides of the object? Is the circuit supposed to wrap around the rectangular object? If only the top needs to be "printed", you could use the Knife Project tool

Comment: In order to avoid a ton of geometry, it might be more efficient to shoot your PCB as a texture, and UV map it onto the surface? If you did need the geometry, you could still use it in a _Displace_ modifier

Comment: Sadly I need the geometry, it is for a 3D printing project. Displace works really well for this though, just a lot of subdivisions needed. Thanks!